# WSO2 IS-KM: encoded password in password grant flow

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to send encoded password in OAUTH2 password grant flow.

```
 POST /token HTTP/1.1
 Host: server.example.com
 Authorization: Basic czZCaGRSa3F0MzpnWDFmQmF0M2JW
 Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

 grant_type=password&username=johndoe&password=<<Encoded Password>>
```

Any leads or documentation in wso2 ?

Comment: Why would you want an encoded password? (well - is it to be sent as URL encoded anyway). If you mean "encrypted" and you don't trust the server, than you can should use other grant types

Answer (score 0):

Any reason why you want the password to be encoded? As it's OAUTH2 so unless the generated token doesn't align with provided username and password the access will be denied.

Comment: I understand, well the problem is oauth client is integrated with angular2 app which inturn exposes the user name and password in the network tab which may lead to security threat. Is there any workaround.

Comment: Since you are talking to the server using HTTPS the parameters or rather the password will be sent encrypted to the server. ie. Although 'your' network tab might show the password in plain text the network traffic is encrypted when you use https. In short the password does not get transmitted in plain text to the server